# Java Swing Jtable show only one row/line

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jtable

hi all i want ask some for little help i can't understand where is my mistake in my code after open the table show me only one player

```
    /**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Player()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 316, 475);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    // create table with data
    // headers for the table
    column = new String[]
    {
        "Id",
        "Name",
        "level",
        "Part Time"
    };      
    for (L2PcInstance pc : L2World.getInstance().getPlayers())
    {
        if (pc.isOnline() && ((pc.getClient() != null) && !pc.getClient().isDetached()))
        {
            // actual data for the table in a 2d array
            data = new Object[][]
            {
                {
                    pc.getId(),
                    pc.getName(),
                    pc.getLevel(),
                    false
                },
            };
        }
    }
    // create table with data
    JTable table = new JTable(data, column);
    contentPane.add(table, BorderLayout.NORTH);

}
```

}

thanks all for your time :) and sorry for bad english

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Please include the rest of your code that instantiates and uses this so others can help debug.

Comment: post us [minimal runnable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about your logic.

In the for loop you keep creating a new instance of your "data" array. So the last instance you create only contains the data from the last row.

You logic needs to be changed to something like:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(column, 0);

for (every row)
{
    Object[] row = {....};

    model.addRow( row );
}

JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Now each row of data is added to the model as you read the data.